# windows service doesn't write files remote server via vpn connection

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, vpn

I'm writing a windows service that must to write log files in a remote server, which is part of my network via secure VPN connection (P2P), so i can write log files in a directory (**like "\10.10.10.10\MylogFolder\log.txt**") via Console Application, that I use to test my business classes.

Via **Console App, it works correctly** but when I try to inject the business class to the service, it doesn't work...

I believe that it's a Installation/Privilege issue, I've already put my WinService to install **using LocalSystem privileges** but it didn't work as well.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalSystem is a very limited account for network access.

You'll need to set the service account to be something that has the required privileges on the remote machine.